# CoreData data fault even accessing property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I assigned a fetch result (NSArray) to a another array so i can show up in a table view easily but all NSManagedObject properties are nil... how can i force the access to persisted database?

Here is my code:

A category to make things simpler:

```
+ (NSString *)CDentityName {
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}
+ (instancetype)CDInsertNewObjectIntoContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[self CDentityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

Allocation:

```
AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *contex = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
HILNetwork * network = [HILNetwork CDInsertNewObjectIntoContext:contex];
network.name = fullDomain;
[delegate saveContext];
```

Fetching:

```
[_user network:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, NSArray * _Nullable networks) {

        NSLog(@"Got %lu networks", networks.count);
        [myNetworks removeAllObjects];

        [myNetworks addObjectsFromArray:networks];
        [tableView reloadData];
        //[appDelegate saveContext];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"FETCH FAILED! %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {}];
```

But then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i alway get:

```
<HILNetwork: 0x6100000fa100> (entity: HILNetwork; id: 0xd000000000540004 <x-coredata://EEDB35CD-8FF3-4E6D-A207-4B57ECC8DC53/HILNetwork/p21> ; data: <fault>)
```

So network name is: (null)

How can i solve? 
This is driving me crazy!

Thanks

Comment: I see you code where you insert the `HILNetwork` into the context, but where do you set the attributes and save the context?

Comment: @JonRose i edited the question adding the info. the problem is when i pass date from an array to another i lose (fault) informations.